# How do I load a page fragment using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-fragments

I have three pages

```
1) index.aspx
2) schools.aspx
3) Classes.aspx
```

All the pages has same **div section** in there pages. Please see below the common **DIV** section in all the pages, however text will be different for each page.

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tabs-container">
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <img width="275" height="220" title="" alt="" src="/99/english/images/fpoSquare.jpg" class="imgRight"></img>
        <p class="destinationSectionHeader first">About Sydney</p><p>Learn English at a Kaplan International Colleges English school! We offer a variety of English courses at over 40 English schools in some of the world's most desirable locations in the UK, Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, USA, Canada and Malta.From fashionable city centre schools to schools on the campuses of prestigious universities, you can take an English course at a Kaplan International Colleges school in the environment that best suits you. All of our English schools provide our students with easy access to great resources and the local area's best cultural, social and historic attractions.
Study in the world-famous Empire State Building in New York, in a beautiful 7-storey art deco building next to the famous Cathedral Square in Christchurch, on Santa Barbara City College's impressive campus, in a historic building in London or in the heart of Sydney. You can have a look at all our schools and English courses by browsing through our website - so take your time and choose the English school that's right for you.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now on **index** page I have got **links** for other two pages (**Schools**.aspx and **Classes**.aspx), when user will click on those links it will show above section based on **div id="tab-container"** taken from those pages and will show in a **div section** of index page below.

```
<div id="contents"></div>
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this functionality using AJAX and JQuery. (It would be good have solution using AJAX)

Thanks!

Update:

All the above links (schools, classes etc) are coming from below html code

```
ul class="tabHead tabs-nav">
    <li class="tabLeftEnd"></li>
    <li class="tabs-selected" id="tab-1">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/index.aspx"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
    <li id="tab-2">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/schools.aspx"><span>Guide</span></a></li>
    <li id="tab-3">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/classes.aspx"><span>Flight Schedule</span></a></li>
    <li id="tab-4">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/specialOffers.aspx"><span>Special Offers</span></a></li>
    <li id="tab-5">
    <a class="load-fragment" href="/photo.aspx"><span>Photos</span></a></li>
    <li class="tabRightEnd"></li>
</ul>
```

If you see there is a class **"tabs-selected"** on selected **li**, I want this to be changed according to the link clicked in the code as suggested by " Marko Ivanovski"

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can easily load page fragments.**

**Update**
*Let's set a class (you can change this to whatever) for every link that we want to load via ajax. This is a good approach because users without Javascript will just navigate to the pages.*

**HTML**

```
<a href="Schools.aspx" class="load-fragment">Schools</a>
<a href="Classes.aspx" class="load-fragment">Classes</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".load-fragment").click(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from going to the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // add tabs-selected class for the selected item
    $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tabs-selected"); //remove selected from other tabs
    $(this).parent().addClass("tabs-selected");

    // store the href in a variable
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // this is the clicked link's href attribute

    // load the data
    $("#contents").load(href + " #tab-container", function() {
        // perform some action when the content is loaded
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');

        // unsure if $(this) works with .load(), use the line below if it doesn't
        $("#contents").fadeIn('slow');        
    });
});
```

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks for the code!, but here you have hardcoded the file name "Schools.aspx", however in my case it would be a dynamic, and it will be called on click event, can you please suggest for this also!.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply Marko, sorry but I have got another issue to be fixed, can you please have a look to my question to the "update" section in the last. Please suggest how to control selected class using your logic. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry Marko, it is removing class from LI,however it failing to add the "tabs-selected" to its parent LI, can you please suggest thanks and also it is not working on IE any ideas

Comment: @Solution - Did you add `var $this = $(this);` to line 6 of my code sample? Are there any JS errors?

Comment: Yes I have added it already, as I told it is working fine in mozilla, however it is adding "tabs-selected" class to <li> and <a> both, and strangely not showing any data in Internet Explorer 8 any ideas and there is no any javascript

Comment: Hmmm it looks fine to me. I've moved the code outside of the load() method, try my update now.

Comment: Sorry Marko it was my fault, its working fine, can you please suggest what can be reason why it is not working in IE 8

Comment: @Solution - it should work in IE8, maybe validate your HTML in case you have some unclosed tags!

Comment: Many Thanks for your answers and suggestions, I will check the HTML!!