# How can I call HTML inside a DIV from a single location?

Tags: html, css

To start off, I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I've created a website that has a top menu. One of the items in the menu is hiking trails.

The format is:

Hiking Trail location
---Names of trails

I plan on having a lot of different trail locations and don't want my HTML to be cluttered up, so I'd like to have this part of my code in a single location which I can edit and the changes show on every page.

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/wKdx0Sbn

```
<div class="header">
  <table id="topmenu" class="header">
  <tr>
  <td class="submen">

    <div style="width: 100%; display: inline;">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li class="top"><a href="../../" class="top_link"><span class="down">Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="../" class="top_link"><span class="down">Hiking Trails</span></a>
          <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="../" class="alltrails"> All Trails </a></li>
            <li><a href="./" class="cmsp"> State Park 1 </a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.html#backside"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#campingg"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#campingf"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#crowders"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#fern"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#lake"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#pinnacle"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#ridgeline"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#rocktop"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#tower"> Trail </a></li>
                <li><a href="./index.html#turnback"> Trail </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../ascg/" class="ascg"> State Park 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="../mnp/" class="mnp"> State Park 3 </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top"><a href="../../contact/" class="top_link"><span class="down">Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help! In the mean time, I'll keep searching.

Comment: you can use either dropdown or you have to use javascript or jquery kind of tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this would to use PHP with using `include` you would save the section of data you want in one file with the extension `filename.php` and then on all the pages you want that file to display you would include it by doing this `<?php include('filepath/filename.php'); ?>` and all your pages that your displaying this on will have to have a `.php` extension also, so something like this

**index.php**

```
<?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
<body>
<div class="body-container">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**header.php Inside folder "includes"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF=8">
  // Rest of your head content
</head>
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <nav class="main-nav">

  </nav>
</header>
```

And just so you know, php has to be on a server to run.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know an alternate way to do it not using PHP? I don't really want the pages to have a php extension. I'll look into it though.

Comment: I take it back! That worked great! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: You could look into doing it with javascript, but honestly I would do it with php it will allow you to do so much more and is definitely worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: inline;">
<ul id="nav">
<li class="top"><a href="../../" class="top_link"><span class="down">Home</span></a>  </li>
<li class="top"><a href="../" class="top_link"><span class="down">Hiking Trails</span></a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="../" class="alltrails"> All Trails </a></li>
        <li><a href="./" class="cmsp"> State Park 1 </a>
          <ul>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function jumpto(x){

if (document.form1.jumpmenu.value != "null") {
document.location.href = x
}
}
</script>
<form name="form1">
<select name="jumpmenu"    onChange="jumpto(document.form1.jumpmenu.options[document.form1.jumpmenu.options.selectedIndex].value)">
<option>Jump to...</option>
<option value="./index.html#homepage">Homepage</option>
<option value="./index.html#javascript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="./index.html#HTML">HTML</option>
<option value="./index.html#CSS">CSS</option>
</select>
</form>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="../ascg/" class="ascg"> State Park 2 </a></li>
<li><a href="../mnp/" class="mnp"> State Park 3 </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="top"><a href="../../contact/" class="top_link"><span class="down">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript and ajax calls.

Algorithm:

```
Get the html fragment with ajax. 
Strip it of any unnecessary tags.(javascript) 
Insert it into the DOM with javascript.
```

If you add jquery to the equation, it gets really trivial as there is already a function for it:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

See this question for a complete example of how to do it:
[How do I load a page fragment using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904152/how-do-i-load-a-page-fragment-using-jquery)

Comment: Thank you! So many great answers and different ways to do things.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this.

**But** since you have not mentioned the basis of your application (php, c#, DB engine...) the simplest way to be independent of databases, csv or xml parsing and alike... is the following.

The code or solution is not optimized and this is just to give you an idea.

1- Create a file named for example trailsList.js and put this in the file (or whatever code you will be re-using):

```
// Trails List
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#backside"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#campingg"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#campingf"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#crowders"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#fern"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#lake"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#pinnacle"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#ridgeline"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#rocktop"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#tower"> Trail </a></li>');
document.write('<li><a href="./index.html#turnback"> Trail </a></li>');
```

2- Call trailsList.js in your document wherever you want the code to appear.

```
.
.
.
  <li><a href="./" class="cmsp"> State Park 1 </a>
   <ul>
    <script src="trailsList.js">
    </script>
   </ul>
  </li>
.
.
.
```