# How do I use a PHP file in root directory with relative paths for other pages?

Tags: php, html

I asked this question the other day:
[How can I call HTML inside a DIV from a single location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714842/how-can-i-call-html-inside-a-div-from-a-single-location)

And I've implemented it into my site but I'm having some issues.

My organizing structure is putting each page into its own folder.

So I have the main index.html in the root and the CSS and PHP header file.

Then I have the other pages in their own folder so I can get rid of the html/php extension.

Now when I put

`<?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>`

into each of the pages, the links are broken because each one needs a different level to access the PHP file in the root directory. Some would be ./ others ../ or ../../

I've found a fix for now which is to use full pathnames:

http://mywebsite.com/trails/, etc.

But I have a feeling there is a better way to do this.

I also thought about putting the header PHP in each directory, but I figure that defeats the purpose of easily editing 1 file to change them all.

The other idea is to put everything into one directory, but I don't want to do that.

So what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Many sites have a config/bootstrap file of some kind in which they place a variable (actually, usually a constant) where they define the document root for the site:

```
defined('DOC_ROOT') || define('DOC_ROOT', __DIR__);
```

They then use this when including their files:

```
<?php include(DOC_ROOT . '/includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! You guys are seriously awesome.

Comment: Quick question. My host is HostGator. When I go into the phpMyAdmin there is a tab called "Server variables and settings." Do I add a variable called config? I guess I'm not real sure where I put the information you've provided.

Comment: I don't think you should being this in phpMyAdmin. This should go into your own code.

Comment: I take it back. Where do I put this part defined('DOC_ROOT') || define('DOC_ROOT', __DIR__); ? Where is this config/bootstrap file?

Comment: Anywhere you want. It could be in your webroot or one level below it. That's where it typically is found.

Comment: Do I just make a file called config? Does it have an extension? config.php?

Comment: Hm. I can't get it to work :( I keep getting this at the top of my page: Warning: include(DOC_ROOT/includes/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/isaac/public_html/index.php on line 18

Comment: Make sure you enclose your path in strings. `include(DOC_ROOT.'/includes/header.php')`

Comment: I have a file in my root directory called config.php with only this line of code inside: defined('DOC_ROOT') || define('DOC_ROOT', __DIR__); and then I have my index.php which is also in the root directory and has this line of code: <?php include(DOC_ROOT.'/includes/header.php'); ?> But it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure that path is correct. Echo it out to your screen to see what says.

Answer (score 4):

Make a variable `($root)` or something and get its real path using PHP's [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

Then do something like:

```
<?php include ($root . '/includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Piet van Dongen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` or define yours:

```
define("MY_WEB_DIR", '/var/www/html');
include(MY_WEB_DIR . '/includes/header.php');
```

Comment: Where do I put the define("MY_WEB_DIR", '/var/www/html');  ?